# Como puedo formatear un de String a fecha con PHP

Tags: php, date, formato

Saludos como están todos

Tengo esta fecha con este formato, es una cadena **Wed Sep 12 2018 14:47:35 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia)** y deseo cobertirla a este formato **2018-09-12 14:47:35** Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar mi problema.

De antemano muchas gracias a todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una instancia de la clase `DateTime` pasándole tu fecha en el formato original que tienes y posteriormente llamar a la función `format` para darle el formato de salida que deseas. Aquí te dejo el ejemplo:

```
//Fecha en el formato original
$fecha = 'Wed Sep 12 2018 14:47:35 GMT-0500';
//Instancia de DateTime con la fecha original
$date = new DateTime($fecha);
//Muestro el texto con la fecha en el formato esperado
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

O puedes hacerlo de esta otra manera

```
//Fecha original
$fecha = 'Wed Sep 12 2018 14:47:35 GMT-0500';
//Establezco la zona horaria a Colombia para que me devuelva bien la hora
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
//Muestro la feha en el formato indicado
echo date('H:i:s', strtotime($fecha));
```

Espero que te haya servido de algo

Comment: Muchas gracias era exactamente lo que estaba buscando

Answer (score 0):

Hace unos días tuve el mismo problema y buscando por Internet me resulto esto y me funciono a la perfección:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');

setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');

echo strftime("%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")
```

prueba y me comentas

si tienes alguna duda o modificación de el formato ya tu investigaras la función `strftime()` en [La documentación de php](http://php.net/manual/es)